# With a multi-tenant application, better alternative to chained CNAME?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, cname-record

Let's assume I have a multi-tenant webserver that runs an application for 500+ domains. I have an AWS Loadbalancer url, my_application.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, which have `A` and `AAAA` records to the actual LB. Now I want to ensure that all the domains I have point to this LB. Then I would see three options:

1. Read the `A` and `AAAA` records from my LB, and copy them for each domain.
2. Make a `CNAME` record for each domain, to the LB url (suggested solution by AWS)
3. Register one custom domain, e.g. applicationdns.com, and create a `CNAME` record to the LB url for e.g. [www.applicationdns.com](http://www.applicationdns.com). Then for each domain create a `CNAME` record to this record ([www.applicationdns.com](http://www.applicationdns.com)).

Of course, option 1 is horribly inefficient so discarded right away.

Option 2 is the suggested approach, which works fine. However, if at any point I would need to migrate the Loadbalancer to a different URL, I would need to fix 500+ DNS records, possibly distributed over multiple providers, so it is hard to automate.

Option 3 would solve this problem, however it introduces a "chained `CNAME`". From what I've seen ([RFC 1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034.html#section-3.6.2)) this is technically valid, but not considered good practice.

What is the best way to approach this challenge? Is there another approach that might work?

Comment: Option two is recommended  (when you actually own and directly manage all those domains) and now is probably a good moment to start automating  your dns management. See https://github.com/StackExchange/dnscontrol for one possible solution for that. - When not you, but your customers manage their own DNS records your option three will work much better. That will simply work as intended in most cases but comes with some concerns as explained here: https://serverfault.com/q/798417/546643

Comment: Another possibility with AWS for additional cost is using their Global Accelerator product with the ALB to get static IPs, and there's also BYOIP if you want/need that control. If customers are pointing their domain apex then they'll need A records rather than CNAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are able to register the custom domain to point to the Loadbalancers in AWS Route53, you can actually make alias `A` (and `AAAA`) records that function similar to `CNAME` records. This prevents chaining `CNAME` records, but still allows you to migrate the Loadbalancer url if necessary.

This is also explained in [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html), you can just repeat the described procedure for AAAA records if you want to support Ipv6.

Answer (score 0):

From an automation point of view, option 1 & 2 automate the same.
Scaling in managed configuration can be done quite swiftly with the help of templates + variables.

I would personally favour 1 over 2, since `CNAME` incur an extra step on domain resolution while adding no real benefit to the ease of configuration, provided (again) you use managed configurations and you do not update them manually.

All in all, the keystone would be how you manage your hundreds of domains' configuration.
Since you are using external providers, the quality of their API seems to be the landmark to look out for.
If you go for self-hosted/managed authoritative name servers, even old technology allows for dynamic reload of individual zones, so there is really nothing standing in the way of automated (rolled out?) deployment.