# SMTP name too long for Canon

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, alias

I am setting up a Canon iR device to scan to email, but their field name for SMTP server is too short for my MX record address.

Is there a way to set-up an alias that would work round this, or some other method?

Why is my MX so long? Because I am using Office 365 so it is of the format  “MyDomain-with-dashes.mail.protection.outlook.com”  (so adding 28 characters to by domain name).

Canon's field seems to be a maximum of 48 characters.
I've logged a support request with Canon but cannot conceivably expect a resolution from them.

Comment: I would point them to RFC 2821 section 4.5.3.1 and ask which part of **256 characters** they found difficult to understand.

Answer (score 5):

You might be able to work around this problem by creating a CNAME in your own domain that resolves to the O365 name. For instance:

```
canon-sucks     IN      CNAME   example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.
```

Then provide `canon-sucks.example.com` to the device.

[Chances are good](https://serverfault.com/q/309651/126632) that this will work; however, if they're that bad at writing Internet software, then who knows...

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP address!!  Duh.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can't reliably use the IP address, because it can and will change.