# Point a subdomain with CNAME to a DDNS subdomain?

Tags: domain, subdomain, network-attached-storage, cname-record, synology

I got a Synology NAS, with different virtual hosts, so i got a DDNS (`user.synology.me`), let's say the virtual hosts are `server1`, `server2` and `server3`, so i can access them using `server1.user.synology.me`, etc.

I pointed my `example.com` to `user.synology.me` using a `CNAME`, then I created a subdomain: `server.example.com`, using `CNAME` pointing it to `server1.user.synology.me`, the problem is, when I go to `server.example.com` it takes me to `user.synology.me`, instead of `server1.user.synology.me`.

What can I do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I go to server.domain.com" and what do you mean by "it takes me to" ? How are you going? What is it?

Comment: If I write server.domain.com the content i receive is the one from domain.com (which is the one from user.synology.me), instead of the content of server1.user.synology.me

Comment: Are you talking about going to a web page?

Comment: What does your DNS table look like? It sounds to me that you have the DNS CNAME and A records setup incorrectly.

Comment: I don't even have a A record, it's like this:
name                   type                  target
domain.com         CNAME           user.synology.me
server                  CNAME            server1.user.synology.me

if i try to make a A record point to user.synology.me it says "Invalid value in dnsrecord"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a CNAME record be used at the apex (aka root) of a domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just "fixed it". In my NAS I had in virtual hosts some hosts created: server1, server2, server3, etc. In the name of the host I had server1.user.synology.me

I just changed it to server.domain.com and now it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think I need to draw a diagram to understand what you're doing here, but to be honest, point your CNAME to the proper A record for the destination. Don't chain CNAMEs.

[RFC1034](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1034.html) allows for chaining in a technical sense, but it is simply poor practice.

A similar question was asked previously, and it's worth looking at the discussion: [Is a CNAME to CNAME chain allowed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309651/is-a-cname-to-cname-chain-allowed)

Comment: Oh, no, i don't want to point a CNAME to a CNAME, i have my DDNS, i pointed my DDNS with a CNAME, i also have subdomains on the DDNS, what i want is to point a CNAME subdomain to a DDNS subdomain, but when i'm doing it instead points my CNAME subdomain to my DDNS root domain.